# Border offset with diferent color overlapping (Solved)

Tags: css, border, offset

I am trying to create an offset border with two differents colors when overlapping the background. I am use to do it witdh rectangles or circles but This is a mix of oval and rectangle.

Here is my attempt:

```css
.square {
  
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 500px 500px 0px 0px;
   border-color: black white white black;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  content:"";
}

.square::after {
  

  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid;
 /* border-color: white black black white;*/
   box-shadow: white 3px 3px 0px inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 500px 500px 0px 0px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

I have test with gradient and box shadow whithout result. Please note that I have read the W3C rules, but I need improve it because the bottom-left is not well done.

As you could see in this next picture (this is really wthat I want) The left bottom border is different and the right top border too (has the same width)

[What I want do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzMxr.jpg)

These are my other attempts (see in full page, please). First example is nice but I can´t change the color overlapping the background. I hope this question was well asked.

```css
*,
::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font: 100 1.25em/1.25 handlee, z003, segoe script, comic sans ms, cursive;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  html {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 240px) {
  html {
    font-size: 0.75em;
  }
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.25em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14em, 1fr));
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
@media (min-width: 37.8125em) {
  body {
  }
}

article {
  --c: #ffa940;
  --s0: calc(1.25em + 6px);
  --s1: calc(1.25em + 6px + 0.5em);
  place-self: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 12em;
  height: 14em;
  border: solid 4px var(--s0);
  border-width: 0 var(--s0) var(--s0) 0;
  padding: var(--s1) 0.5em 0.5em var(--s1);
  background: var(--c) padding-box;   
}

article {
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}
article::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -60px;
  border: inherit;
  border-width: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 14em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px var(--c);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 
  
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ffa940;
  border-top-left-radius: 400px;
  border-top-right-radius: 400px;
  transform: translateY(10px);
 
}
.container:after {
  width:12px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:284px;
  left:-13px
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-top-left-color: black;
  border-right-color: white;
  /* border-top-color: white;*/
  border-top-left-radius: 400px;
  border-top-right-radius: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: -13px;
}
.white-grad {
  --b:5px;  /* border width*/

  color: #313149;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height:250px;
 /* aspect-ratio: 1;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  left:500px;
  background: red;
   border-radius: var(--r,50%);
}

.white-grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570));
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r,50%);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
         mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
 -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
 mask-composite: exclude;
  left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <article>   </article>

<dic class=" container"> </div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:4px;--r:5em 5em 0 0;--c:linear-gradient(-56.03deg,white 49.5%,black 0)"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what the problem is. Could you describe some more, and perhaps include an image of what the result is supposed to look like?

Comment: Thanks. I have added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. there was a simple way too easy simply with z-index:

```css
*,
::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font: 100 1.25em/1.25 handlee, z003, segoe script, comic sans ms, cursive;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  html {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 240px) {
  html {
    font-size: 0.75em;
  }
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.25em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14em, 1fr));
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
@media (min-width: 37.8125em) {
  body {
  }
}
article {
  --c: #ffa940;
  --s0: calc(1.25em + 6px);
  --s1: calc(1.25em + 6px + 0.5em);
  place-self: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 12em;
  height: 14em;
  border: solid 4px var(--s0);
  border-width: 0 var(--s0) var(--s0) 0;
  padding: var(--s1) 0.5em 0.5em var(--s1);
  background: var(--c) padding-box;   
}

article {
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
article::before {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -60px;
  border: 4px solid white;  
  width: 12em;
  height: 14em; 
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;  
}
.bottom{
  z-index:-2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  left: 235px;
  border: 4px solid black;  
  width: 12em;
  height: 13.2em; 
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;  
}
```

```html
<article></article>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
```

Please note that I have changed the left and top values in the snippet because the render was different. Can be changed easy to perform better the effect. My correct values in desktop are:  top: 59px;
left: 300px;

(I don't know why the snippet is different when I post it.. When I insert it seems to be correct.)